# what best module for creating a paid listing in joomla?

Tags: php, content-management-system, joomla

what is the best module for creating a paid listing in joomla? Im kinda newbie in joomla and trying to create a paid listing in my website.And i want the when the user subscribed to the paid listing his/her or her post will be pending before and reviewed by the admin before posting it to the website.

thanks!

Comment: Does "ditch Joomla! and install something decent" count as a module?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you find a component that is purpose built, then you are going to have to do some creative set up to make this type of thing work. I would start with AEC which is a paid membership management tool. It will handle the subscription part of the equation and put paid members in to the group that you want.

The next part can be done several ways. I am a fan of K2 so I would probably set up a group in K2 that allows front end contributions, but no publishing rights. This would allow you to moderate the submissions before they are live on the site. AEC integrates with K2 so you should be able to make it work with a little tinkering.

AEC is commercial, you can get it here - http://valanx.org/

K2 is free, you can get it here - http://getk2.org/

Valanx does offer installation services, you may consider that if you have problems with the setup. Their pricing seems to be pretty reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by a paid listing, but adsmanager seems to be what you are looking for. It allows your users to pay for advertisements (or listings) on your website. They can pay extra if they wish their advert to be "Featured" on your site.
You can have admin approve the adverts before being published.
http://www.joomprod.com/classified-ads
demo http://psdemo.joomprod.com/